# WPF: ListBox with WrapPanel, No scroll bars, content scaled with ViewBox, showing all content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, viewbox

Using a WPF ListBox and a WrapPanel, is there a way to use a ViewBox with the internal content scaling, but without having any content trimming or scroll bars? I want to scale all internal items down. The width / heigth of the container can scale, and the number of items is dynamic.

I put together a simple WPF example (without any solutions). Open to sugguestions.

Code Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfListBoxWrapPanel.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="230.572"
    Width="426.972">
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection, FallbackValue=123456123456123456123456123456123456}"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="50"
                      Height="50"
                      Margin="3">
                    <Rectangle Fill="LightCoral"></Rectangle>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                               Margin="4"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

[image: Preview of above rendered code]

Thanks!

Comment: You mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871767/how-can-i-achieve-this-mix-of-stackpanel-and-uniformgrid-behavior/22871980#22871980) with each item shrinking? Or just making each item's fit each while retaining resolution? Having trouble visualizing what exactly you mean by shrinking the content?

Comment: @ChrisW.,I think he means that the last row of the WrapPanel should automatically have elements that have the Height of 5 or 10.

Comment: @LupuSilviu Ooooh, you mean just making it all fit within the view area boundary of a fixed window? I'm not sure the reasoning for the fixed Height/Width set on the Window of `Height="230.572" Width="426.972"` since if he just removes those it would scale to fit child content, but with each square hard set at 50x50 I don't think ViewBox is what is actually needed here. So the OP would help with some further clarification.

Comment: Correct, with each item shrinking. I had a little success moving it to a UniformGrid panel template and each item a ViewBox, but it wasn't perfect.  Now its just a challenge.

Comment: Well if you instead remove the hard set height/width on your parent of each item then uniformgrid should scale accordingly, alternatively if viewbox is actually a viable option (like if this is for images and stuff with resolution concerns) you can apply the same technique I have in that first link around the ItemsPresenter.

Comment: Yea, this is just an example prototype from what we have in our main application.  But in our main app, its similar in fashion where we have these large like touch-friendly selections.  So removing the width/heigth would make it not look uniform with the different contents that are stored within.